# What is the difference between Open in Live Server and Open in Default browser

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a music player with a song visualizer. All my songs are on my PC.

For making the visualizer, I am using this code.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    canvas = document.getElementById("cnv1");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    audioctx = new AudioContext();
    WIDTH = window.innerWidth - 50;
    canvas.width = WIDTH - 50;
    HEIGHT = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;
    analyser = audioctx.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = SAMPLES;
    oscillator = audioctx.createOscillator();
    oscillator.connect(audioctx.destination);
    source = audioctx.createMediaElementSource(music);
    source.connect(analyser);
    source.connect(audioctx.destination);
    freqArr = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    barHeight = HEIGHT;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
});

function draw() {
    if (!music.paused) {
        bigBars = 0;
        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 255;
        x = 0;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqArr);
        for (var i = 0; i < INTERVAL; i++) {
            if (barHeight >= (240)) {
                bigBars++;
            }
            let num = i;
            barHeight = ((freqArr[num] - 128) * 3) + 2;
            if (barHeight <= 1) {
                barHeight = 2;
            }
            r = r + 10;
            if (r > 255) {
                r = 255;
            }
            g = g + 1;
            if (g > 255) {
                g = 255;
            }
            b = b - 2;
            if (b < 0) {
                b = 0;
            }
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
            context.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, (WIDTH / INTERVAL) - 1, barHeight);
            x = x + (WIDTH / INTERVAL);
        }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

When I am running my code by clicking on **Open in Live Server**, it is working fine, but when I am running the same code by clicking on **Open in Default browser**, it is not working

I am using VS Code as a Code Editor.

Answer (score 0):

There may be 2 reasons:-
File format not supported
Invalid file location.

Try using the file with a Web format and check the location of the file.
To check the location of the file, right click on the file and go to the properties option. Now go to the security option and copy and paste the path given in object name.

Comment: No. The problem is what the error message says the problem is.